# How to edit the CSS styling for SSRS Report Viewer controls with aspx? (visual studio 2022)

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, visual-studio-2022

Been searching the internet on how to do this but alot of the existing documentation is outdated.

I was able to render the Report Viewer Controls using the following lines of code in an aspx page:

```
     <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" Height="100%" Width="100%">
        <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="" ReportPath="" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

The report viewer controls function correctly and are able to generate parameterized reports. However the formatting for some of the buttons are misaligned and I would also like to space out some of the fields.

[image]

Is there a way to edit the styling for the actual interface itself?

Comment: Never seen it looking like this. Have you looked with browser debugging tool  (F12) which styles were applied to the buttons? Not sure how to apply custom styles, since the report is iframed with the control.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I would consider upgrading the report system. (even with nuget).
That layout does look wonkey.

I as a general rule never styled the report tool bar - not sure if you can.

but, mine looks like this:

[image]

So, I never felt the need to mess around - I think the built in one looks ok.

but, your tool bar does not look quite right - I would as noted consider updating that componet, as the later versions do look a lot better.

(and "later" of course is a relative term - this is webforms, and the report object is quite old).

Comment: The latest version of Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms is installed. (150.1484.0)